# Object starts with?

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel

Is there a way to see if an object exists in Maya, but only search for a partial object name?

Example, search for an object that starts with `object`, but it's actual name is `object_001`.

Is there a way to do this? As it stands I only know how to search for a specific name:

```
if (objExists('object_001'):
    //Do Something
```

But obviously the `obj` stringwould have to be exact to the object e it self.

Comment: If you know it will always be a number you could try a loop with something like light = 'Light_%d' % (light_id) |  or there are some python string functions that you could try searching the hiearchy

Answer (score 1):

Pymel [`ls`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.general/pymel.core.general.ls.html#pymel.core.general.ls) seems to accept directly a regular expression matching names, thus the following should work - provided that matching elements exists, a non-empty list will be returned; and a non-empty list in boolean context will be evaluated as `True`, whereas an empty will be `False`.

```
if ls(regex='object.*'):
    ...
```

Comment: You also don't need to specify a regex flag. `ls('object*')` will do just as well.

Comment: Remember to use r=True if namespaces are available

Comment: I know I said starts with in the question, however if I have an object labeled 'Titles_labelGroup_1', labelGroup is always static, it never changes, so how can I perform the regex if labelGroup exists anywhere?